# Is it needed to add one more version to already existing app on appstore for push notification?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, apple-push-notifications

I have an app on appstore and now I need to send a push notification and i have not written any code to that app. So now to add push notification  to my app do I need to add one more version to it and schedule a push notification to it or can I do the same to the available version of my app on appstore?

Comment: sorry if any of you find my question irrelevant but I want to clear my doubt before writing any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a new version of your app, since you have to build your app with a provisioning profile that supports push notifications, and you have to add code to your app that would register the app to Apple Push Notifications Service, and send the device token to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the following code in your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    return YES; 
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken { 

    NSString *deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""]; 
    NSLog(@"Device Token === %@", deviceTokenString); 
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error { 
    NSLog(@"Error in getting Device Token === %@", error); 
}
```

Then run your app on a device. When you do so, you will be asked for permission to display Push Messages from your application. If you allow, then the method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will get called and your device token will be printed on the console.